# Regex: Last Occurrence of a Repeating Character

Tags: regex, regex-group

So, I am looking for a Regex that is able to match with every maximal non-empty substring of consonants followed by a maximal non-empty substring of vowels in a String

e.g. In the following strings, you can see all expected matches:

```
"zcdbadaerfe" = {"zcdba", "dae", "rfe"}

"foubsyudba" = {"fou", "bsyu", "dba"}
```

I am very close! This is the regex I have managed to come up with so far:

```
([^aeiou].*?[aeiou])+
```

It returns the expected matches except for it only returns the first of any repeating lengths of vowels, for example:

```
String: "cccaaabbee"

Expected Matches: {"cccaaa", "bbee"}

Actual Matches: {"ccca", "bbe"}
```

I want to figure out how I can include the last found vowel character that comes before (a) a constant or (b) the end of the string.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: It looks like you wanted to write [`[^aeiou].*?[aeiou]+`](https://regex101.com/r/HG85Is/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const rgx = /[^aeiou]+[aeiou]+(?=[^aeiou])|.*[aeiou](?=\b)/g;
```

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `[^aeiou]+` | one or more of anything BUT vowels |
| `[aeiou]+` | one or more vowels |
| `(?=[^aeiou])` | will be a match if it is followed by anything BUT a vowel |
| `|` | OR |
| `.*[aeiou](?=\b)` | zero or more of any character followed by a vowel and it needs to be followed by a non-word |

```js
function lastVowel(str) {
  const rgx = /[^aeiou]+[aeiou]+(?=[^aeiou])|.*[aeiou](?=\b)/g;
  return [...str.matchAll(rgx)].flat();
}

const str1 = "cccaaabbee";
const str2 = "zcdbadaerfe";
const str3 = "foubsyudba";

console.log(lastVowel(str1));
console.log(lastVowel(str2));
console.log(lastVowel(str3));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern is slightly off.  I suggest using this version:

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+[aeiou]+
```

This pattern says to match:

- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+` a lowercase non vowel, one or more times
- `[aeiou]+` followed by a lowercase vowel, one or more times

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR3BnH/2).

Comment: Class ranges of course, that's slick.+1